# Google Cloud Vertex AI with Golang: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unexpected HTTP status code received from server: 404 (Not Found)

Tags: go, grpc, gcloud, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform

I have a Vertex AI model deployed on an endpoint and want to do some prediction from my app in Golang.

To do this I create code inspired by this example : https://cloud.google.com/go/docs/reference/cloud.google.com/go/aiplatform/latest/apiv1?hl=en

```
const file = "MY_BASE64_IMAGE"

func main() {

    ctx := context.Background()

    c, err := aiplatform.NewPredictionClient(cox)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("QueryVertex NewPredictionClient - Err:%s", err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    parameters, err := structpb.NewValue(map[string]interface{}{
        "confidenceThreshold": 0.2,
        "maxPredictions":      5,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("QueryVertex structpb.NewValue parameters - Err:%s", err)
    }

    instance, err := structpb.NewValue(map[string]interface{}{
        "content": file,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("QueryVertex structpb.NewValue instance - Err:%s", err)
    }

    reqP := &aiplatformpb.PredictRequest{
        Endpoint:   "projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION_ID/endpoints/ENDPOINT_ID",
        Instances:  []*structpb.Value{instance},
        Parameters: parameters,
    }

    resp, err := c.Predict(cox, reqP)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("QueryVertex Predict - Err:%s", err)
    }

    log.Printf("QueryVertex Res:%+v", resp)
}
```

I put the path to my service account JSON file on GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
But when I run my test app I obtain this error message:

```
QueryVertex Predict - Err:rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unexpected HTTP status code received from server: 404 (Not Found); transport: received unexpected content-type "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
QueryVertex Res:<nil>
```

Comment: Hello @garrym. Can you let me know if your issue is resolved?

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, consider upvoting and accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well :)

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @DazWilkin suggested, configure the client option to specify the specific [regional endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest#service-endpoint) with a port 443:

```
option.WithEndpoint("<region>-aiplatform.googleapis.com:443")
```

Try like below:

```
func main() {
 
   ctx := context.Background()
   c, err := aiplatform.NewPredictionClient(
       ctx,
       option.WithEndpoint("<region>-aiplatform.googleapis.com:443"),
   )
   if err != nil {
       log.Printf("QueryVertex NewPredictionClient - Err:%s", err)
   }
   defer c.Close()
       .
       .
```

Comment: did not work for me. I get "request contains an invalid endpoint"

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I tried your last exemple and we make a progress. Now the error is the following : `rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = Invalid instances: struct_value {}`
I will make some tests to find where this come from.

Comment: Ok it works, the error come from some comments I have added during the test. Thanks you @DazWilkin and Vishal K

Comment: This answer helped me solve the same issue with Python.

Comment: Thank you very much! You've saved up my time a lot!

Comment: Yes, solved my problem!!! Gracias !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this

```golang
[...]
url := fmt.Sprintf("%s-aiplatform.googleapis.com:443", location)
[..]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).